# Bootstrap: Display text on hover image

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am creating a website for the first time with Bootstrap3 and have a page with 3 images which will be links to galleries. These images are not thumbnails.

I have alternative images (B+W) for hovering and so my code currently changes the image from colour to B+W on hover.

I want to be able to also include a text overlay on hover so people will know to click through to the gallery. So, I'm looking to add text on hover to the B+W image. Alternatively, I would make the colour image less opaque and add text to that, if it's easier!

Here's my html code currently.

```
<a href="landscapes.html"> <img src="landscape.jpg" alt="Landscape" onMouseOver="this.src='landscapebw.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='landscape.jpg'" class="img-circle img-responsive"> </a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a question, but a request to do some work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `title` attribute :

```
<a href="landscapes.html" title="yourtext"> <img src="landscape.jpg" alt="Landscape" onMouseOver="this.src='landscapebw.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='landscape.jpg'" class="img-circle img-responsive"> </a>
```